# Accented characters within include file in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, include

I have a webpage that outputs a string that contains accented characters.

I have the variable `$myGlobalStr` that is declared in the main page, and then is returned via the function `outputGlobalVariable()`. Everything work as expected.

When I declare that very same string within the function `outputFunctionVariable()`, the output is in UTF-8 format..

I tried to use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` in my page, ad I also tried to include `header('Content-type: text/html; iso-8859-1')` at the beginning of my include file. Both doesn't work.

I never had to specify a charset in an include file before. I know I can use the function `utf8_decode()` in outputFunctionVariable() but I'm interested to understand why it's happening and the logical behind this...

I'm using Zend Server CE on Windows.

**index.php**

```
<?
    $myGlobalStr = "1. Dites bonjour à l'élève.";
    include("includes/functions.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=outputGlobalVariable()?>
<hr>
<?=outputLocalVariable()?>

</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?
    function outputGlobalVariable() {
        global $myGlobalStr;

        return $myGlobalStr;
    }

    function outputLocalVariable() {
        $myStr = "2. Dites bonjour à l'élève.";

        return $myStr;
    }
?>
```

**output**

```
1. Dites bonjour à l'élève.
------------
2. Dites bonjour Ã  l'Ã©lÃ¨ve.
```

Comment: Maybe the editor you're using to modify these pages is screwing things up, and it's not PHP's fault at all. After all, functions.php is a different file than index.php, so the trashing could've happened long before PHP got hold of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the files contains the strings in ISO-8859-1, and the other as UTF-8 string.
Now that your page is declared with the Latin-1 charset, the latter will come out with garbage characters.

Don't mix the two. Either identify the UTF-8 script and convert it back to Latin-1. Or move to UTF-8 for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the .php files (both index.php and functions.php) are saved with utf-8 BOM you might also try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Anyway it's good idea to be consistent between the encoding you are using along all your .php files as well as the meta tag and the Content-Type HTTP response header.